# precision multiplication of 255-bit integer in radix-2^16

Tags: c, cryptography, precision, multiprecision

I would like to implement the precision multiplication of 255-bit integer in `radix-2^16 in C`.

I have been suggested to present such big number as an `array of bignumber[16] ( typedef uint16_t bignumber[16] )`. However, I don't get the intuition behind that ( as i know it can also be bignumber[8] with typedef uint32_t).

**Then how do I perform multiplication of those big numbers?** In order to check result ( with sage for example), I need to print those numbers in base 10, but I dont know how to do it.

Any help to clearly explain the concept would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: not really, I referred that post before posting the question.

Comment: Then what are you asking?  Your question title suggests you want to know how to do multiplication with more bits than available datatypes.  But then you seem to be asking how to convert it to base 10 and display it.

Comment: so what I am asking is:
1. presenting number in different radix base as I mention 255-bit integer, why there are multiple ways to present it?
2. the multiplication of such two numbers. Let say if i use uint64_t bignumber[16] to present for 255bit nubmer, then how the multiplication goes? ( I am especially unclear with the carry)